# Docker-compile instruction to command

Tags: docker, redis, elasticsearch

```
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    volumes:
     - $RESOURCES_FOLDER/redis:/data  
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:2.4
    command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
    volumes:
     - $RESOURCES_FOLDER/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Above is the content in docker-compose. Assume I have both redix and elasticsearch 2.4 installed, and I just need to read in data specify in volumes, what should I do? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Read where? Inside the container? Which volumes? Where do you have redis and elastic search installed?

Comment: @muru Assume there is no container, and all data are accessed directly in operating system, and redis and elastic search are all in operating system directly.

Comment: Then just use the `$RESOURCES_FOLDER/elasticsearch` and `$RESOURCES_FOLDER/redis:/data` directories directly in redis and elastic search.